# Hosting an ASP.net application on a subfolder

Tags: asp.net, redirect, subdirectory, reroute

I got a hosting space with Godaddy and I have multiple domain names referring to the same host space.

One of the application is an ASP.net and is located in a subfolder with the domain name related referring to that subfolder.

So `www.mydomain.com` is referring to `<hosting-space-root>\myapp`

I found that sometimes the application is correctly handling redirections:
e.g. `www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx` links to `www.mydomain.com/Other.aspx`

But some other times, the links jumps to a url similar to:

```
www.mydomain.com/myapp/Other.aspx
```

Which works fine with no errors, but doesn't look nice.

What is the reason for that and how to handle it?

The application is non-MVC and is actually a very simple one. Do I need to do rerouting and/or implement IHttpModule? Or is there a simple configuration to tell ASP.net that is your root folder use it?

Comment: Actually I found that the links working fine are the HTML links e.g. <a href="/Other.aspx">
And the ones that are redirecting to the URLs with appending the subfolder, are the ones that are server side e.g. <asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="Other.aspx" />

Comment: Have you tried using the tilde to direct it to the virtual root of your app directory?  Like `~/Other.aspx`, for instance?

Comment: I think that worked. But still I need in some cases to use relative links (in this case linking to pages in the same folder as the source page).

Comment: I went ahead and post my comment as an answer.  Please take a second to accept it (by clicking the checkmark next to the answer) if it solved your problem.  Can you expand on what your other issue is?  I'd be glad to try and help with that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you state:

> ...the ones that are redirecting to the URLs with appending the
>   subfolder, are the ones that are server side e.g. `<asp:LinkButton
>   runat="server" PostBackUrl="Other.aspx" />`

You should us the `~/` syntax to create relative URLs (relative to your application root, that is).  That should resolve the issue you're having with server controls.  Like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Other.aspx" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves the issue, but still I need to be able to use relative links